# when uisng NSKernAttributeName - UIFieldEditorContentView is wider than UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to format value in UITextField as grouping 4 characters (like xxxx xxxx xxxx ....) using NSKernAttributeName on every 4th character

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *result = nil;    
    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[stringToFormate length]-1; i++) {
                if (i>0 && (i+1)%4 == 0) {
                    [result addAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName : @(4.0f)} range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
                }
                else {
                   [result addAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName : @(0.0f)} range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
                }
            }
    }
```

Problem is that content where the text is drawn is wider than textfield frame. Maybe the UITextField doesn't know how to work with kern attribute.

Any suggestion, how to solve this?? THANKS!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out one solution. It works but it's not very sofisticated...

Only way how could I convince content area TO UPDATE itself was GO LEFT AND GO RIGHT:

```
UITextPosition *beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument;
            UITextPosition *cursorLocation = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:(range.location + string.length)];
            UITextPosition *cursorLocation2 = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:(range.location - 1 + string.length)];

        if(cursorLocation) {
            // set start/end location to same spot so that nothing is highlighted
            [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cursorLocation2 toPosition:cursorLocation2]];
            [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cursorLocation toPosition:cursorLocation]];
        }
```

-whole solution including this fix is here:

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField //resign first responder for textfield
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }


    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        textField.attributedText = [self fourDigitFormattedIban:textField.text];

        UITextPosition *beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument;
        UITextPosition *cursorLocation = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:(range.location + string.length)];
        UITextPosition *cursorLocation2 = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:(range.location - 1 + string.length)];

        if(cursorLocation) {
            // set start/end location to same spot so that nothing is highlighted
            [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cursorLocation2 toPosition:cursorLocation2]];
            [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:cursorLocation toPosition:cursorLocation]];
        }

        return NO;
    }


- (NSAttributedString*)fourDigitFormattedIban:(NSString*)string {

    NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSMutableAttributedString *result = nil;
    if (stringWithoutSpaces) {
        result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringWithoutSpaces attributes:nil];
        if ([stringWithoutSpaces length] > 0) {
            for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[stringWithoutSpaces length]-1; i++) {
                if (i>0 && (i+1)%4 == 0) {
                    [result addAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName : @(4)} range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
                }
                else {
                    [result addAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName : @(0.0f)} range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```